# DatePicker '@y0c/react-datepicker' default value

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I am using DatePicker from [`@y0c/react-datepicker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@y0c/react-datepicker), I want to be able to set a default value, but I can't, I have set `DefaultValue` or a selected, but none shows the value, do you have any idea?

```
<Panel>
     <DatePicker onChange={onChange("DatePicker")} defaultValue='00/00/0000'/>
</Panel>
```

Comment: You coud use `initialDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [`dayjs`](http://zetcode.com/javascript/dayjs/) and you can add `initialDate` like

```
<Panel>
  <DatePicker
    // to set default date
    initialDate={dayjs("2018-06-03")}
    onChange={onChange("DatePicker")}
    // to format date
    dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD"
  />
</Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DatePicker
            showTimeOnly
            dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            selected={*some value*}
            initialDate={dayjs("2012-12-02", "yyyy-MM-dd")}
            name="startTime"
            onChange={(time) => this.callSomeMethod(time, i, 'startTime')}/>
```